# GWT - Refresh page Issues when I clicked on Broswers Refresh/reload button

Tags: gwt

When I am login in GWT Application, it will open my dashboard but when I am click on browsers refresh/reload button it will call entry point of my application and it will load my login page.
So how can I stop this issue.
How can I stay at same page when I am click on Browsers refresh button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save user info in session after logging in and check it in your entry point class before calling login form/method and than decide to show login form or not.

But I think, the better way is not to write login logic by hands, but to integrate [spring-security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) to your gwt application. It will do all logic by itself, you need only to create login page (you can write login page not in gwt) and make it work with gwt.
Spend week if needed to understand how it works and you will have no problems in future.

Comment: Yes you are right and thanks for your quick answer. But when I login successfully and at dashboard I am click on browser refresh button and it will load login page not same page why?

Comment: No it will not, cause spring security checks session and if user is already logged in spring will show the dashboard page, otherwise it will redirect user to login page. You will have 2 pages - one for gwt another for spring login.